Show that $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-yx}\sin(x)dx=\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ for $y>0$ using Feynman's trick
I'm working on this question in my analysis course. Problem:
Show that $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-yx}\sin(x)dx=\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ for $y>0$
Earlier I was familiar with the Feynman's integration trick, had a general idea what it was about but never before had a chance to use it. I might be wrong, but this integral seemed like a good one to try this trick on.
What I did is wrote the same integral as a function $I(y)$ and differentiated everything and then got:
$I'(y)=\int_0^{\infty}-xe^{-yx}\sin(x)dx$
Since I never used this trick before I was not sure if I needed to introduce a new parameter or can I use $y$ as I did here?
When I keep on with evaluating this integral at a certain moment I got stuck:
$\sin(x)\frac{x}{e^{yx}}+\frac{1}{e^{yx}}\rvert_0^\infty-\int_0^{\infty}e^{-yx}(\frac{x}{y}+1$$)\cos(x)dx$
As said I'm not sure if I applied the method right, or if it's solvable this way. I just know that the first term in the last expression goes to zero so I'm technically just left to deal with the last integral. I'd be thankful for an advice on this and a hint on how to proceed towards the solution.

Just like in integration by parts (which is how you usually do this integral), express the new integral in terms of the old. You now have $I'(y) = -xI(y).$ Now what?

Why not just use integration by parts? Do it twice and you will have a multiple of the integral you started with. If you want a useful 'trick', look up the tableau method  of integration by parts.

@SeanRoberson why $-xI(y)$?

Looks like I misspoke @SineoftheTime.

For this particular integral, a simpler trick is to use the identity $\sin(x)=\Im(e^{ix}).$

The antiderivative must be  of the form $$c(y)e^{-xy}\sin x+d(y) e^{-xy}\cos x$$ Find $c(y) $ and $d(y)$ by applying $d/dx.$

Are you sure the problem statement is correct? There's a standard example of "Feynmann's Trick" where this integral appears in an intermediate step: Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}x ,dx$ by introducing the function $I(y) := \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \frac{\sin x}x ,dx$, so that the desired integral is $I(0)$ and $I'(y) = -\int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x ,dx = -\frac{1}{1 + y^2}$. Applying the F.T.C. gives $\lim_{y \to \infty} I(y) - I(0) = \int_0^\infty -\frac{dy}{1 + y^2} = -\arctan y \vert_0^\infty = -\frac\pi2$, so $I(0) = \frac\pi2$.

Note that " Feynman's trick " is nearly as old as calculus itself. Now, for this proposed integral to consider there are times to use tricks and there are times to just do the work in a simple way. First,
\begin{align}
f(y, a) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y x} \, \sin(a x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2 i} \, \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- (y - a i) x} \, dx - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(y + a i) x} \, dx \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2 i} \, \left( \frac{1}{y - a i} - \frac{1}{y + a i} \right) = \frac{a}{y^2 + a^2}. 
\end{align}
So far the integral has been evaluated. But, the intent is to find another way. In this view consider two derivatives with respect to $a$:
$$ \frac{d^2 \, f}{d a^2} = - \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 \, e^{- y x} \, \sin(a x) \, dx. $$
Using $D_{y} e^{- y x} = - x \, e^{- y x}$ then
$$ \frac{d^2 \, f}{d a^2} = - \frac{d^2 \, f}{d y^2} $$
or
$$ \left( \frac{d^2}{d a^2} + \frac{d^2}{d y^2} \right) \, f(y, a) = 0.$$
The solution to this equation is
$$ f(y, a) = \frac{a}{y^2 + a^2}. $$
This is the same result as before. The solution this way is not as easy as the simple evaluation of the integral.
A use of the trick is handy when evaluating integrals of the form
$$ f_{n}(y, a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n \, e^{- y x} \, \sin(a x) \, dx. $$
In this case it is quickly determined that
$$ f_{n}(y, a) = (-1)^n \, \frac{\partial^n}{\partial \, y^n} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- y x} \, \sin(a x) \, dx = (-1)^n \, \frac{\partial^n}{\partial \, y^n} \, \left( \frac{a}{y^2 + a^2} \right) $$
which leads to
$$ f_{n}(y, a) = \frac{a \, (-1)^n \, n!}{(y^2 + a^2)^{n+1}} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} \binom{n+1}{2k+1} \, (-1)^k \, a^{2k} \, y^{n - 2k}. $$
Another example is applied in the following. Consider the integral
$$ I_{n} = \int_{0}^{a} x^n \, \ln(x) \, dx $$
for which (by use of $x^n = e^{\ln(x^n)} = e^{n \, \ln(x)}$)
\begin{align}
I_{n} &= \int_{0}^{a} x^n \, \ln(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{a} \ln(x) \, e^{n \, \ln(x)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \, \int_{0}^{a} e^{n \ln(x)} \, dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \, \int_{0}^{a} x^n \, dx \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial n} \, \left( \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1} \right) = \frac{a^{n+1} \, \ln(a)}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}.
\end{align}
Now, consider the evaluation of an integral that uses this result. For example:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\ln(x) \, dx}{1-x} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, \int_{0}^{1} x^n \, \ln(x) \, dx  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{a^{n+1} \, \ln(a)}{n+1} - \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} \right) \\
&= \ln(a) \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n^2} \\
&= - \text{Li}_{2}(a) - \ln(a) \, \ln(1-a), 
\end{align}
where $\text{Li}_{2}(x)$ is the dilogarithm function. This result differs from a result obtained by use of Wolfram Alpha (by the returned result when I used Wolfram Alpha). For the case of $a = 1$ this reduces to a known result
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x) \, dx}{1-x} = - \text{Li}_{2}(1) = - \zeta(2). $$
There are, of course many other examples that could be found, but being provided two gives a basis of why the derivative with respect to a parameter is useful. Including sometimes adding in a second parameter (see the first example).

A technique Feynman learned from Woods’ Advanced Calculus, which probably was familiar to Euler, definitely merits the name Feynman’s trick.
